# How do I select a range programatically in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
active  date        name
1       1-Jun-2013  Paul
1       4-Jun-2013  Sheela
1       8-Jun-2013  Paul
1       2-Jul-2013  Henrik
        3-Jul-2013  Henrik
        10-Jul-2013 Paul
        14-Jul-2013 Sheela
```

I want a counter for {how many times a name is mentioned AND active == 1}.   In practice, the active = 1 is manually set when the date has passed, so the criteria could instead be {how many times a name is mentioned AND date < today}.

The resulting list should be like this:

```
Henrik  1
Paul    2
Sheela  1
```

I can use `=IFCOUNT(C2:C8, "Henrik")` to count all occurances of "Henrik", but that doesn't take the active (or date) column into account.

So, If I could programatically select C2:C5 (since A5 is the last date with active == 1, or the B2:B5 cells have a date < today) or make the `IFCOUNT` check for active == 1 in addition to cellcontent == "Henrik", that would solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of doing it is to make another column with

`=IF(A2=1,C2,"")`

```
A2 being the active flag and then do the `COUNTIF` on that column.
```

You could also replace the `A2=1` with a date test if you wanted.

Comment: Yup, this worked great.  Thanks!